# The layout page "~/Views/Shared/" could not be found at the following path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here's a new twist on this old error.  Many of my pages use a layout page so they have this near the top

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout;
}
```

Where viewbag layout is set in an action filter applied to the controller as such

```
namespace somenamespace.Controllers {
    [SessionSettings]
    public class MyController : Controller {
```

where the action filter does this

```
public class SessionSettings : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        dynamic viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        string layout = some database lookup
        if (layout == null) layout = "_defaultLayout.cshtml";
        viewBag.layout = layout
```

and this works pretty well, most of the time.  But when I check the Event Logs - Applications - I see Warnings, event ID 1309, event code 3005, "An unhandled exception has occurred"  "The layout page "~/Views/Shared/" could not be found at the following path: "~/Views/Shared/"."

And here's the kicker, often event happens on pages that DON'T use the Layouts, they have this at the top

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...
```

Anyone have any thoughts on that?  Thx

Comment: Did you debug it and watch the ViewBag.layout? maybe try: `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout ?? ""`

Comment: I would like to suggest another approach: [How to set a Razor layout in MVC via an attribute filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4057429/858757) and you can extend that attribute with the option to pass in a custom name. This way the Viewstart would only be used when no attribute was provided.

Comment: W92 - unfortunately the error never happens on my machine and in production its intermittent.

Comment: @Silvermind - I looked into this and basically its the same thing I'm doing.  They are just using OnResultExecuting instead of OnActionExecuting.  Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @nuander It doesn't abuse the ViewBag and it works.

Comment: well my action filter is doing a lot more then just setting the layout.  I need a general solution.  I'm going to try using Session instead of view bag and see if that is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I traced through the source and found that the issue is with when you set `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout;`

When this property is set, the method [`WebPageExecutingBase.NormalizeLayoutPagePath(string path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpageexecutingbase.normalizelayoutpagepath(v=vs.111).aspx) is called.

This basically creates an absolute/relative path and then checks if a *file* exists with that name. Because `ViewBag.layout` is null, this fails and so errors (you can see the source for this method on [codeplex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/WebPageExecutingBase.cs), about halfway down.

It doesn't matter that you later set `Layout = null`, the `_ViewStart` code is called first so the error happens.

Your best option I can see is to just check if `ViewBag.layout` is null before setting it:

```
if(ViewBag.layout != null)
{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout;
}
```

I think in this way, you also don't need to explicitly set it to `null` if they do not have a layout.

Comment: I think that `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout ?? ""` is  shorter syntax.

Comment: OK I'll check into this _ViewStart and report back

Comment: Hmmm I'm not using ViewStart so I'm not sure this applies

Comment: @W92 If `ViewBag.layout` is not set, `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/" + ViewBag.layout ?? ""` still gives `"~/Views/Shared/"` which is exactly the same as the OP.

Comment: checking for null is a good idea I will add that to my code, thx